Remote eSIM Activation on Android IoT Device using Flutter App
Developing a Flutter app for a custom Android IoT device. Is it possible to remotely activate an eSIM on the device through a flutter app from a mobile, considering Flutter's limitations?
Are there any alternative solutions or APIs from device manufacturers that I could integrate with Flutter for remote eSIM activation?
Thanks in advance
I have started R&D to do this using bluetooth connectivity; but I am not sure is it feasible or not till now.
